# ¿Porque mi estado se actualiza solo en un if, pero no el else?

Tags: flutter

Estoy trabajando en flutter una funcion lamda que actualizara el estado de un widget con el objetivo de que la animacion de un lottie se muestre durante un segundo, y posterior a ello se muestre el boton original.

Cuando la variable idCall tiene un valor, el proceso funciona correctamente, sin embargo cuando entra en el else (Cuando la variable esta nula) la animacion no se muestra y solo queda un bloque en blanco, luego del tiempo estipulado ya se muestra el boton. Este es mi codigo:

Boton:

```
Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: ButtonGlobal(
          onTerminoAnimacion: () {
            setState(() {
              widget.mostrarAnimacion = false;
            });
          },
          onClick: () async {
            ActualizarCapacidadLogic.actualizarCapacidad(
                context: context,
                pais: widget.controllerPaisAC.text,
                canal: widget.controllerCanalAC.text,
                sucursal: widget.controllerSucursalAC.text,
                folio: widget.controllerFolioAC.text,
                sucursalGestora: widget.controllerSucursalGestoraAC.text,
                motivoSeleccionado: widget.itemSeleccionado,
                onChangeCargandoActualizarCapacidad: (bool newValue){
                  setState(() {
                    widget.cargandoActualizarCapacidad = newValue;
                  });
                },
                idCall: widget.currentCall?.idCall.toString(),
                onChangeMostrarAnimacion: (bool newValue){
                  setState(() {
                    widget.mostrarAnimacion = newValue;
                  });
                }
            );
          },
          label: "Actualizar capacidad",
          processLoading: widget.cargandoActualizarCapacidad,
          showAnimation: widget.mostrarAnimacion,
        ),
      )
```

Esta es la logica del boton (La funcion actualizarCapacidad):

```
 static Future<void> actualizarCapacidad(
  {required BuildContext context,
  required String pais,
  required String canal,
  required String sucursal,
  required String folio,
  required String sucursalGestora,
  required String motivoSeleccionado,
  required Function(bool newValue) onChangeCargandoActualizarCapacidad,
  required String? idCall,
  required Function(bool newValue) onChangeMostrarAnimacion,
  }) async {

if (pais == "" ||
    canal == "" ||
    sucursal == "" ||
    folio == "" ||
    sucursalGestora == "" ||
    motivoSeleccionado == Consts.seleccioneMotivoActualizar) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Alert(title: Consts.avisoDialgoTitle, content: Consts.camposVaciosDialog);

      });
} else {
  ClienteService clienteServiceAC = ClienteService();
  onChangeCargandoActualizarCapacidad(true);
  final response = await clienteServiceAC.actualizarCapacidad(
      pais: pais,
      canal: canal,
      sucursal: sucursal,
      folio: folio,
      sucursalGestora: sucursalGestora);

  if (response is SuccessModel) {
    ReporteService serviceReporte = ReporteService();
    final responsereport;

    Map<String, dynamic> datosBitacoraCapacidad = {
      Consts.clienteUnicoCDB: "$pais-$canal-$sucursal-$folio",
      Consts.sucursalCDB: sucursalGestora
    };

    if(idCall != null){
      responsereport = await serviceReporte.createReport(
          tipoReporte: Consts.helpDeskTypeReport,
          idPlantilla: getIdTemplateWithMovCapacidad(motivoSeleccionado),
          idSucursal: sucursal,
          idCall: idCall,
          reference: jsonEncode(datosBitacoraCapacidad),
          typeOperation: Consts.actualizarCapacidadTypeOperation);
      if (responsereport is ErrorModel) {
        ErrorModel error = responsereport;
        onChangeCargandoActualizarCapacidad(false);
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Alert(
                  title: Consts.avisoDialgoTitle,
                  content:
                  "${Consts.titleErrorInsertReport} ${error.message}. ${error.exception ?? ""}");
            });
      } else {
        onChangeCargandoActualizarCapacidad(false);
        onChangeMostrarAnimacion(true);
      }
    }else{
      MovimientoService serviceMovto = MovimientoService();
      final responseBitacora = await serviceMovto.insertBitacora(idSucursal: sucursal, typeMovto: Consts.actualizarCapacidadTypeOperation, reference: jsonEncode(datosBitacoraCapacidad));
      if(responseBitacora is ErrorModel){
        onChangeCargandoActualizarCapacidad(false);
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Alert(
                  title: Consts.avisoDialgoTitle,
                  content:
                  "${Consts.titleErrorInsertBitacora} ${responseBitacora.message}. ${responseBitacora.exception ?? ""}");
            });
      }else{
        onChangeCargandoActualizarCapacidad(false);
        onChangeMostrarAnimacion(true);
      }
    }
  } else {
    ErrorModel error = response;
    onChangeCargandoActualizarCapacidad(false);

    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Alert(
              title: Consts.avisoDialgoTitle,
              content: "${Consts.titleErrorActualizarCapacidad} ${error.message} . ${error.exception ?? ''}");
        });
  }
}
```

}

Y este es el widget del boton donde esta la animacion:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return widget.processLoading?
    const Center(child: Cargando()) :
    widget.showAnimation?
    Lottie.asset(
        "assets/check_animation.json",
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        controller: AnimationController(
            vsync: this,
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1)
        )..addStatusListener((status) {
          if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
            widget.onTerminoAnimacion();
          }
        })..forward()
    ):
    FilledButton(
        onPressed: widget.enabeld ? (){
          if(widget.onClick !=null ){
            widget.onClick!();
          }
        } : null ,
        child: Text(widget.label)
    );
```

}

Validaciones hechas:

1. Se verifica que el estado si se cambia, por medio de prints
2. Se cambio el orden de las validaciones del if, siempre se cumple solo cuando el idCall no es nulo
3. Se pone un showAlertdialog y este si se muestra, es solo el cambio de la animacion el que no funciona

[image: Cuando el estado esta como cargando]

[image: Cuando la animacion si se muestra]

[image: Cuando la animacion no se muestra]